# what is the meaning of "scrub diagnostics" in the line?

Tags: meaning

Scrub diagnostics.
- Sir? - Did you hear me? Initiate the launch.
T-minus five minutes to launch.
Auto sequence has been initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrub is a noun, but it is *also* a verb which means to discard or throw away (albeit somewhat informal).

In other words, the meaning here is "forget the diagnostics."